# Blender - Inserting a text button using bpy

Tags: user-interface, blender, bpy

I'm designing a simple GUI for a Blender 2.80 plug-in. I've created a dialog box to enter some data:

[image]

I would like to replace the line of text ("Lorem ipsum ...") with a button with a custom label (example "click here to visit our website").

Below is the code I am using:

```
class ExportFDSCloudHPC(Operator):

    bl_idname = "..."
    bl_label = "Title"
    bl_description = "..."

    data1 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Text 1",
        default = "..."
    )

    data2 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Text 2",
        default = "..."
    )

    data3 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Text 3",
        default = "..."
    )
    
    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align = True)
        col.prop(self, "data1")

        self.layout.label(text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit...")

        col = self.layout.column(align = True)
        col.prop(self, "data2")

        col = self.layout.column(align = True)
        col.prop(self, "data3")

    def execute(self, context):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get button you need to provide an existing [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout%20operator#bpy.types.UILayout.UILayout.operator): `row.operator("wm.save_as_mainfile")` button text is defined in operator. If you want to change name of existing operator use `row.operator("wm.save_as_mainfile", text='My Save Label')`

You can create own operator:

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator" # <- put this string in layout.operator()
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator" # <- button name

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

and then use it like that:

```
[..]
col.prop(self, "data1")
col.operator("object.simple_operator")
# self.layout.label(text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit...")

col = self.layout.column(align = True)
[..]
```